# Telegram API: How do I get messages from a public channel, which I am not participant of?

Tags: telegram

I am able to successfully retrieve messages from a channel via [channels.getMessages](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/dev/Telegram/Resources/scheme.tl#L1116) request, once I know their `message IDs`. I find channel id by [contacts.search](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/dev/Telegram/Resources/scheme.tl#L987), by the way.

At the moment, mesage IDs are consequtive integers, so getting max_id would solve the issue.

I am sure it possible, since official clients do this (view a channel without joining it). I will try to find out how official desktop app does this by reading [its sources](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop), but any help will be much appreciated.

I need this because am writing a simple public telegram channel -> rss/web interface.

Please do not confuse Telegram Client API with Telegram Bot API. Bot API allows to receive 'push' messages on new messages, but no 'reading historical logs'.

Comment: How do you use channels.getMessages? does it have to be like `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/channels.getMessages`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the steps you have to do in order to get messages from a channel you're not joined:

1. Resolve the username into ID and access_hash with `contacts.resolveUsername`
2. Invoke `messages.getHistory` to get your desired messages

Here is a short description of `messages.getHistory` parameters:

```
peer:        The channel from whom to retrieve the message history
limit:       Number of messages to be retrieved
offset_date: Offset date (messages *previous* to this date will be retrieved)
offset_id:   Offset message ID (only messages *previous* to the given ID will be retrieved)
max_id:      All the messages with a higher (newer) ID or equal to this will be excluded
min_id:      All the messages with a lower (older) ID or equal to this will be excluded
add_offset:  Additional message offset (all of the specified offsets + this offset = older messages)
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out messages.getHistory is just okay, gives you last N messages + total count.